# Variable set to global does not style element

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, styles

I have the following code:

```
let fireball; //global variable

fireball = document.createElement("img") //variable on local
fireballArray.push(someFunction(fireball, {
 src: "img.png", width: "38" }))

fireball.style.display = "none" //global variable
```

My objective is that `fireball = document.createElement("img")` can be styled (in this case, hidden)

However, `document.createElement("img")` does not hide. Any help? Thanks

Warning: `fireball = document.createElement("img")` this variable must remain on local scope and style.display: none must be on another scope (as seen on code)

Comment: Because you called this: ```document.createElement("img")``` on local, I think it can't be styled (only on the same scope) I think

Comment: Did you try to make it as `fireball.setAttribute("style", "display:none;");` ?

Comment: Well, actually I wanted to display none when user clicks a button (so it must be displayed none after)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your img:

```
function myFunction() {
  var fireball = document.createElement("img");
  fireball.setAttribute("src", "img_pulpit.jpg");
  fireball.setAttribute("width", "304");
  fireball.setAttribute("height", "228");
  fireball.setAttribute("alt", "The Pulpit Rock");
  fireball.setAttribute("id", "UniqId"); // It is important to set an uniq ID
  document.body.appendChild(fireball);
}
```

Then to apply the set, get the Element by Id `getElementById`:

```
function myFunction2() {
  var fireball = document.getElementById("UniqId");
  fireball.setAttribute("style", "display:none; border:3px solid red;");
  document.body.appendChild(fireball);
}
```

You can try with w3C demo : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_img_create

Comment: You can style it directly when you call it. `var fireball = document.createElement("img");
  fireball.setAttribute("style", "border: 3px solid red");
  document.body.appendChild(fireball );`

Comment: Yes but I want to style it after

Comment: You dont really need that. if you dont want, you can remove it. it just to apply it. Specialy that it does not make sens to apply it on a get element by Id as there is only 1